# Rewriting max-min problem using strong duality

Tags: optimization, maxima-minima, duality-theorems

I have rewritten a max-min problem as a unique maximisation problem using strong duality. I have built a Matlab code which seems to show that my derivations are wrong. However, the code itself may be wrong. Therefore, I would like your help to firstly understand whether the math below is correct.

This is the original  **problem (1)**
\begin{equation}
\begin{alignedat}{3}
 \max_{b\in \mathbb{R}^{L}} &&&  \min_{\substack{\text{$Z_1\in \mathbb{R}^{L+1}$}\\ \text{$Z_2\in \mathbb{R}^{K}_{\geq 0}$}}} 
\Big[b^T \text{ } \text{ } \text{ }0 \text{ } \text{ } \text{ }0_{K}^T\Big] Z,\\
 \text{s.t. }   &&&    b^Tb\leq 1, \\
  &&&   A_{\text{eq}}\text{ }Z = B_{\text{eq}},\\
 &&&   A_{\text{ineq}} \text{ }Z \leq 0_{d_{\text{ineq}}},  
\end{alignedat}
\end{equation}
where: $Z\equiv (Z_1, Z_2)$ is an $(L+1+K)\times 1$ vector; $O_K$ is a $K\times 1$ vector of zeros; $d_{\text{ineq}}$ is the number of rows of $\text{A}_{\text{ineq}}$; $d_{\text{eq}}$ is the number of rows of $\text{A}_{\text{eq}}$ (used below); $0_{d_{\text{ineq}}}$ is a $d_{\text{ineq}}\times 1$ vector of zeros; $ \mathbb{R}^{K}_{\geq 0}$ is the $K$-dimensional Euclidean space of positive numbers.

Now, I transform the inner minimisation problem into a maximisation problem using strong duality and obtain **problem (2)**.

\begin{equation}
\begin{alignedat}{3}
 \max_{\substack{\text{$b\in \mathbb{R}^{L}$} \\ \text{$\lambda_{\text{eq}}\in \mathbb{R}^{d_{\text{eq}}}$} \\ \text{$\lambda_{\text{ineq}}\in \mathbb{R}^{d_\text{ineq}}_{\geq 0}$}}} &&& \Big[ -B_{\text{eq}}^T \text{ } \text{ } \text{ }0_{d_{\text{ineq}}}^T\Big] \lambda,\\
 \text{s.t. }   &&&    b^Tb\leq 1, \\
  &&&   [A^T]_{1:|L|}\text{ } \lambda = \begin{pmatrix}-b\\ 0\end{pmatrix},\\
 &&&  -[A^T]_{L+1:\text{end}} \text{ }\lambda \leq 0_{K},  
\end{alignedat}
\end{equation}
where: $\lambda\equiv (\lambda_{\text{eq}}, \lambda_{\text{ineq}})$ is a $(d_{\text{eq}}+d_{\text{ineq}})\times 1$ vector;  $A$ is the  $(d_{\text{eq}}+d_{\text{ineq}})\times( L+1+K)$ matrix obtained by stacking one on top of the other the matrices $A_{\text{eq}}$ and $A_{\text{ineq}}$, and $[A]_{i:j}$ denotes the sub-matrix of $A$ containing the rows $i,i+1,...,j$ of $A$.

If I have applied correctly strong duality, then the **value of (1) is equal to the value of (2)**. Are my derivations correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ and $C\in\mathbb{R}^{p\times n}$ and consider the linear program in general form $\inf\{c^\top z : Az = b, Cz \le d, z\in\mathbb{R}^n\}$. Then Lagrangian is
\begin{equation*}
L(z,\lambda,\mu) = c^\top z + \lambda^\top(Az-b) + \mu^\top(Cz - d),
\end{equation*}
where $\mu\ge 0$. This is affine in $z$, and therefore the dual function is
\begin{align*}
g(\lambda,\mu) = \inf_{z\in\mathbb{R}^n}L(z,\lambda,\mu) = \begin{cases} -b^\top \lambda - d^\top\mu &\text{if $c+A^\top \lambda + C^\top\mu = 0$}, \\
-\infty & \text{otherwise}. \end{cases}
\end{align*}
Therefore, the dual problem becomes
\begin{align*}
&\text{maximize}&& -b^\top\lambda - d^\top \mu \\
&\text{subject to}&&c+A^\top\lambda + C^\top\mu = 0, \\
&&&\mu \ge 0,
\end{align*}
where the optimization variables are $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}^m$ and $\mu\in\mathbb{R}^p$.

Now, let's transform your inner linear program into the general form above. The objective is $f(z) = (b,0_{K+1})^\top z$, so $c = (b,0_{K+1})$. The equality constraint is $A_\text{eq}z = B_\text{eq}$, so $A=A_\text{eq}$ and $b=B_\text{eq}$. Finally, the inequality constraint is $A_\text{ineq}z \le 0_{d_\text{ineq}}$, so $C = A_\text{ineq}$ and $d = 0_{d_\text{ineq}}$. Putting these into our dual problem above, we find that the dual to the inner minimization is
\begin{align*}
&\text{maximize}&& -B_\text{eq}^\top \lambda - 0_{d_\text{ineq}}^\top \mu \\
&\text{subject to}&& \begin{bmatrix}b \\ 0_{K+1}\end{bmatrix} + A_\text{eq}^\top\lambda + A_\text{ineq}^\top\mu = 0, \\
&&& \mu\ge 0,
\end{align*}
which looks similar to your dual. I see one major difference: your dual should enforce the constraint that the dual variables associated with the primal inequality are nonnegative, i.e. $\mu\ge 0$. In your formulation, it looks like you are using $A_\text{ineq}^\top \mu \ge 0$ instead. In general, this will not suffice to constrain $\mu\ge 0$. If you already have code solving your dual problem, I suggest checking whether the resulting optimal dual variable $\mu^*$ is indeed elementwise nonnegative. If it's not, try fixing the constraint as outlined above. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks (+1). Before selecting it as answer, I think the constraint you are referring to is written below the max symbol: $\lambda_{\text{ineq}}\in \mathbb{R}^{d_{\text{ineq}}}_{\geq 0}$. Correct?

Comment: Ah, yes! I missed that. In that case, I think you can remove the constraint $A_\text{ineq}^\top \mu \ge 0$ (the final inequality constraint in your dual). Let me know if that fixes your problem!